# Why does objects I create in functions are not modified by other functions? (C++)

Tags: c++, list, object

I'm having problems using objects in C++. My University teacher assigned us a work in which we have to build a class named Lista (I'm Italian) with every feature it has in its specifics such as setElement, readElement, Head and so on. I'll post my files so you can read what I wrote. My problem is that the Lista object I create in the function "fondi" in servizilista.cpp is not modified by inserisci() function. Whether there could be problems with variables names I'll translate them in English.

Nodo.h

```
//
//  Nodo.h
//  Lista con Doppio Riferimento
//
//

#ifndef Nodo_h
#define Nodo_h

template <class tipoelem>
class Nodo {
public:
    tipoelem valore;
    Nodo* successivo;
    Nodo* precedente;
    
    Nodo();
    ~Nodo();
};

template <class tipoelem> Nodo <tipoelem> :: Nodo () {
    successivo = NULL;
    precedente = NULL;
}

template <class T> Nodo <T> :: ~Nodo () {}

#endif /* Nodo_h */
```

Lista.h

```
//
//  Lista.h
//  Lista con Doppio Riferimento
//
//

#ifndef Lista_h
#define Lista_h

#include "Nodo.h"

template <class tipoelem>
class Lista {
public:
    typedef Nodo <tipoelem> *posizione;
    
    Lista();
    ~Lista();
    bool vuota();
    posizione primo();
    bool fine(posizione);
    posizione successivo(posizione);
    posizione precedente(posizione);
    tipoelem leggi(posizione);
    void scrivi(posizione, tipoelem);
    void inserisci(posizione, tipoelem);
    void rimuovi(posizione);
    int ottieniLunghezza();
    
private:
    posizione testa;
    int lunghezza;
};

template <class tipoelem> Lista <tipoelem> :: Lista() {
    lunghezza = 0;
    testa = NULL;
}

template <class tipoelem> Lista <tipoelem> :: ~Lista() {}

template <class tipoelem> bool Lista <tipoelem> :: vuota() {
    return (testa == NULL);
}

template <class tipoelem> typename Lista <tipoelem> :: posizione Lista <tipoelem> :: primo() {
    return testa;
}

template <class tipoelem> bool Lista <tipoelem> :: fine(posizione pos) {
    return (pos -> successivo == NULL);
}

template <class tipoelem> typename Lista <tipoelem> :: posizione Lista <tipoelem> :: successivo(posizione pos) {
    return (pos -> successivo);
}

template <class tipoelem> typename Lista <tipoelem> :: posizione Lista <tipoelem> :: precedente(posizione pos) {
    return (pos -> precedente);
}

template <class tipoelem> tipoelem Lista <tipoelem> :: leggi(posizione pos) {
    return (pos -> valore);
}

template <class tipoelem> void Lista <tipoelem> :: scrivi(posizione pos, tipoelem elem) {
    pos -> valore = elem;
}

template <class tipoelem> void Lista <tipoelem> :: inserisci(posizione pos, tipoelem elem) {
    Nodo <tipoelem> *nodo = new Nodo <tipoelem>;
    
    nodo -> valore = elem;
    
    if(pos == testa and testa == NULL) {
        nodo -> successivo = NULL;
        testa = nodo;
    }
    else if(pos == testa and testa != NULL) {
        nodo -> successivo = pos;
        pos -> precedente = nodo;
        testa = nodo;
    }
    else if (pos != testa and pos == NULL){
        posizione iter = primo();
        while(!fine(iter)) {
            iter = iter -> successivo;
        }
        
        nodo -> successivo = NULL;
        nodo -> precedente = iter;
        iter -> successivo = nodo;
    }
    else if (pos != testa and pos != NULL) {
        nodo -> successivo = pos;
        nodo -> precedente = pos -> precedente;
        pos -> precedente -> successivo = nodo;
        pos -> precedente = nodo;
    }
    
    lunghezza ++;
}

template <class tipoelem> void Lista <tipoelem> :: rimuovi(posizione pos) {
    Nodo <tipoelem> *temp = pos;
    
    if(pos == testa)
        testa = pos -> successivo;
    else {
        pos -> precedente -> successivo = pos -> successivo;
        
        if(pos -> successivo != NULL)
            pos -> successivo -> precedente = pos -> precedente;
    }
    
    pos = pos -> successivo;
    
    lunghezza --;
    
    delete temp;
}

template <class tipoelem> int Lista <tipoelem> :: ottieniLunghezza() {
    return lunghezza;
}

#endif /* Lista_h */
```

servizilista.h

```
//
//  serviziolista.h
//  Lista con Doppio Riferimento
//
//

#ifndef serviziolista_h
#define serviziolista_h

#include "Lista.h"

void stampa(Lista <double>);
Lista <double> epura(Lista <double>);
Lista <double> fondi (Lista <double>, Lista <double>);

#endif /* serviziolista_h */
```

servizilista.cpp

```
//
//  serviziolista.cpp
//  Lista con Doppio Riferimento
//
//

#include <iostream>
#include "serviziolista.h"

using namespace std;

void stampa(Lista <double> l) {
    Lista <double> :: posizione iter = l.primo();
    
    cout << "[";
    while(iter != NULL) {
        cout << l.leggi(iter);
        
        if(l.successivo(iter) != NULL)
            cout << ", ";
        
        iter = l.successivo(iter);
    }
    cout << "]\n\n";
}

Lista <double> epura(Lista <double> l) {
    Lista <double> :: posizione s1;
    Lista <double> :: posizione s2;
    Lista <double> :: posizione temp;

    s1 = l.primo();
    while(s1 != NULL) {
      s2 = l.successivo(s1);
      while(s2 != NULL) {
        if(l.leggi(s1) == l.leggi(s2)) {
            temp = l.successivo(s2);
            l.rimuovi(s2);
            s2 = temp;
        }
        else {
          s2 = l.successivo(s2);
        }
      }
      s1 = l.successivo(s1);
    }
    
    return l;
}

Lista <double> fondi(Lista <double> l1, Lista <double> l2) {
    Lista <double> l;
    Lista <double> :: posizione p1 = l1.primo();
    Lista <double> :: posizione p2 = l2.primo();
    Lista <double> :: posizione pl = l.primo();
    double e1, e2;
    
    while(p1 != NULL and p2 != NULL) {
        e1 = l1.leggi(p1);
        e2 = l2.leggi(p2);
        
        if(e1 < e2) {
            cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e1 << ".\n";
            l.inserisci(pl, e1);
            p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
            cout << "Valore in pl: " << l.leggi(pl) << ".\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e2 << ".\n";
            l.inserisci(pl, e2);
            p2 = l2.successivo(p2);
            cout << "Valore in pl: " << l.leggi(pl) << ".\n";
        }
        
        pl = l.successivo(pl);
    }
    
    while(p1 != NULL) {
        l.inserisci(pl, l1.leggi(p1));
        p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
        pl = l.successivo(pl);
    }
    
    while(p2 != NULL) {
        l.inserisci(pl, l2.leggi(p2));
        p2 = l2.successivo(p2);
        pl = l.successivo(pl);
    }
    
    return l;
}
```

main.cpp

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Lista con Doppio Riferimento
//
//

#include <iostream>
#include "Lista.h"
#include "serviziolista.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Lista <double> l1;
    Lista <double> l2;
    Lista <double> lista;
    
    l1.inserisci(l1.primo(), 4);
    l1.inserisci(l1.primo(), 1);
    l1.inserisci(l1.primo(), 2);
    
    l2.inserisci(l2.primo(), 3);
    
    cout << "Lunghezza l1: " << l1.ottieniLunghezza() << ".\n";
    cout << "Lista l1: ";
    stampa(l1);
    
    cout << "Lunghezza l2: " << l2.ottieniLunghezza() << ".\n";
    cout << "Lista l2: ";
    stampa(l2);
    
    lista = fondi(l1, l2);
    
    cout << "Lunghezza lista fusa: " << lista.ottieniLunghezza() << ".\n";
    cout << "Lista fusa: ";
    stampa(lista);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of pass by value. Are you familiar with Pass by value and pass by reference?

Comment: Yes, I do but my teacher said we have to respect its representation written in his own book. So, I did as he wrote in his book...

Comment: Could you give us the expected output?

Comment: fondi() basically fuses two lists into one single list by comparing each value of the two lists and copying each time the minor element until all the elements are copied into that resulting list.

Comment: When I run your code through ```valgrind```, I get the error ```Access not within mapped region at address 0x0``` for the function ```Lista<double>::leggi(Nodo<double>*)```. and ```fondi```.

Comment: So, what does that means?

Comment: When I use inserisci() in main.cpp the lists are modified but, when I use it in functions in servizilista.cpp it returns me errors.

Comment: I am not sure what you expect to get but you have a very simple memory corruption here - you create list `l` as an empty list, then you point `pl` to the first element of the list (and since it is empty it is NULL), then you insert a value into list `l` (no problem with that, it works), but naturally `pl` is still NULL you never modified it. Is that your problem? What do you need it to do exactly?

Comment: I want to put an element creating a new node in Lista l by using, each time, the variable pl to set the position. The first time I declare pl it points to l's head which is NULL but, inside inserisci() I create a new node. which has three values: element, next node reference and previous node reference. But, how should I do to update pl in order to take l's head memory reference?

Comment: Son of a gun. Those aren't pass by value. They are `typedef`ed pointers. Do what your instructor asks, but know for when you get to industry that concealing the types of variables should be done carefully. For example, in this case I wrote your question off as trivial because I misread it.

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to say, user4581301. What's the mistake in your opinion? How would you fix this code in order make it work properly?

Comment: added answer explaining what I see is wrong. I think @YuriNudelman also spotted the problem (but may not have explained it sufficiently). This suspicion is confirmed by his recent updates. Have an upvote, Yuri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list code seems OK.

Problem is with how you use it - you never update the variable `pl`. So do something like that:

```
    if(e1 < e2) {
        cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e1 << ".\n";
        l.inserisci(pl, e1);
        p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
        pl = l.primo();
        cout << "Valore in pl: " << l.leggi(pl) << ".\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e2 << ".\n";
        l.inserisci(pl, e2);
        p2 = l2.successivo(p2);
        pl = l.primo();
        cout << "Valore in pl: " << l.leggi(pl) << ".\n";
    }
```

EDIT: OK, now I am getting what you are trying to do.
Again, list implementation is OK.

To add element to list head you shoulf call `l.inserisci(l.primo(), e1);`

To add element to the tail - `l.inserisci(NULL, e1);`

Here what you want is to always add to tail. So forget about the variable `pl`. Completely. Drop it, you don't need it. Your code becomes much simpler:

```
while(p1 != NULL and p2 != NULL) {
    e1 = l1.leggi(p1);
    e2 = l2.leggi(p2);
    
    if(e1 < e2) {
        cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e1 << ".\n";
        l.inserisci(NULL, e1);
        p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e2 << ".\n";
        l.inserisci(NULL, e2);
        p2 = l2.successivo(p2);
    }
}

while(p1 != NULL) {
    l.inserisci(NULL, l1.leggi(p1));
    p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
}

while(p2 != NULL) {
    l.inserisci(NULL, l2.leggi(p2));
    p2 = l2.successivo(p2);
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. This function is part of a Natural merge sort. I read your code and saw that you wrote pl = l.primo(). But, what I want to do is to put every time a new value in the next void position of the list. For example:

L1 = [4, 1, 2]
L2 = [3]

The resulting list should be: L = [3, 4, 1, 2]. So, if I initialize pl each time to the first node of l how can I write every time in the next position of the list?

Comment: Now I get what you are trying to do, see the edit above

Comment: May the God of programmers reserve his right seat to you. Thank you, you just saved my brain from melting...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the bug you are hunting, but I can't explain this well in a comment. May the downvotes have mercy on my soul.

I'm going to annotate some code.

```cpp
Lista <double> fondi(Lista <double> l1, Lista <double> l2) {
    Lista <double> l; //<-- empty list
    Lista <double> :: posizione p1 = l1.primo();
    Lista <double> :: posizione p2 = l2.primo();
    Lista <double> :: posizione pl = l.primo(); //<-- first item in empty list. pl is null
    double e1, e2;

    while(p1 != NULL and p2 != NULL) {
        e1 = l1.leggi(p1); //<-- get value at p1
        e2 = l2.leggi(p2); //<-- get value at p2

        if(e1 < e2) { //<-- let's say e1 is less than e2 and we enter this case
            cout << "Valore da inserire in pl: " << e1 << ".\n";
            l.inserisci(pl, e1); //<-- insert to pl in l. pl is not changed. It is still null
            p1 = l1.successivo(p1); //<-- updates p1, not pl
            cout << "Valore in pl: " << l.leggi(pl) << ".\n"; // attempts to get value at pl
                                                              // but pl is null. Kaboom.
        }
```

`p1 = l1.successivo(p1);` advances `p1` that's p-the-number-one. The next line `l.leggi(pl)` uses `pl` that's p-the-letter-L. `Lista <double> :: posizione pl = l.primo();` and `pl` is null.

Not 100% sure what you want to do here, but I suspect

```
        p1 = l1.successivo(p1);
```

should be advancing `pl`, not `p1`

```
        pl = l1.successivo(pl);
```

If not, I have no clue what you're trying to do and can make no suggestions. The code is still fatal, though.

Suggestion: use descriptive names that don't differ by a single letter. They're too easy to mix up especially `l` and `1`.

Comment: You are right for what concerns not updating pl from NULL to the very first node of the list once it is updated with the first value, but in that place I have not to update pl, but p1 because the next value I have to consider is the next in l1. In fact, I update pl, too but after the if-else statement.

Comment: No worries. All I can claim is English and French, and that French would get me killed in many French-speaking parts of the world.